# I added ScatterPlot View But I can not See it on Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot class like:

```
@interface myCPTScatterPlot :  UIView <CPTPlotDataSource , CPTScatterPlotDelegate ,    CPTScatterPlotDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;

-(void) initAll;
-(void) configureHost;
-(void) configureGraph;
-(void) configurePlots;
-(void) configureAxes;

@end
```

and I implemented all configure functions. I created a graph and added it into host:
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

I implemented myCPTScatterPlot.mm file well.

I have an initWithframe function in myCPTScatterPlot.mm file like:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Finally, I have a pageView.mm file and I added all page objects into my page.view in there

```
[(UIView *)page performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:firstScatterPlot waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but I can not see my chart :(

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did it. element object that I want to add into view(Page) should be CPTGraphHostingView.
Than everything will be fine.

```
[(UIView *)page performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:firstScatterPlot waitUntilDone:YES];
```